# reading files using fgetc

Tags: fgetc

I have a question about using fgetc to count characters in a specified file.
How do you use it when you have to count character types separately? Like for example I only want to count the number of lowercase characters only, or number of spaces, or punctuations, etc? Can someone show a brief example? Thank you

I tried to do this program that would hopefully count the total number of characters, how do you squeeze in though the number of the separate character types? I'm not exactly sure if this program is correct

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    //Local declarations
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    FILE* fp;

    //Statements
    if (!(fp = fopen("piFile.c", "r")))
    {
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
    return (1);
}//if open error

      while ((a = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)
      {
      if (a != '\n')
      count++;
      printf("Number of characters: %d \n", count);

      else
      printf("There are no characters to count.\n");
      }
      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your if/else is a syntax error because the `if` part is not in curly braces. Please provide a compilable C file, preferably with indentation reflecting the code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on these functions:

```
   int isalnum(int c);
   int isalpha(int c);
   int isascii(int c);
   int isblank(int c);
   int iscntrl(int c);
   int isdigit(int c);
   int isgraph(int c);
   int islower(int c);
   int isprint(int c);
   int ispunct(int c);
   int isspace(int c);
   int isupper(int c);
   int isxdigit(int c);
```

and you'll see right away how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your while,  you can use if statements for each character you want to check.

```
if(isalnum(a){
    counta++;
}
else if(isalpha(a)){
    countb++;
}
else if(isascii(a)){
    countc++;
}
```